# Nginx Reverse Proxy fails to proxy some urls

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

So I've been using NGINX to serve my API under an `/api/v1/` path, which has been working fantastically well for 3 projects that I've been working on.

But today one of my API resources is returning a 404 with the NGINX 404 Page.  All the other Urls on the API still work fine, and if I request directly from the proxy resource, I get the correct response.

This is the current NGINX config I have...

```
location /api/v1 {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8088/api/v1/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_connect_timeout 600; 
    proxy_send_timeout 600; 
    proxy_read_timeout 600; 
    send_timeout 600;

    expires -1;
}
```

If I query `/api/v1/ts/` I get the expected response, if I query `/api/v1/ts/schema.json` I also get the expected response, but if I query `/api/v1/ts/grouped.json` I get the NGINX 404 page.

The NGINX error logs shows that it failed to open the static file (non-proxied stuff)...

```
[error] 27038#27038: *114 open() "/path/to/static/files/api/v1/ts/sheet/grouped.json" failed (2: No such file or directory), ....
```

Why is NGINX trying to locate the file locally, when it's been defined as part of the reverse proxy path?

Comment: Do you have special location that covers static files(including .json)?

Comment: You can use `location ^~ /api/v1` to avoid conflicts with your *regular expression* `location` blocks.

Comment: @metallic, not in this case.   Richard Smith, seems that your suggestion sorted it.  Can you please post as an Answer, so I can submit it as the answer.  :)